# How to set NegativeButton of AlertDialog.Builder unclickable

Tags: android, android-dialog

My code as below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setTitle("Dialog");

dialog.setPositiveButton("Check", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    if(condition) {
      //set NegativeButton unclickable
    } else {
      //set NegativeButton clickable
    }
  } // end of onClick
});

dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

How to set NegativeButton clicked and unclickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to check the condition in onclick:

```
try {
 Field field = dialog.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mShowing");   
 field.setAccessible(true);   
 field.set(dialog, false);
}
catch(Exception e) { 
 e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

This can make it do nothing, but it still clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
... ...

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();

if(condition) {
  //set NegativeButton unclickable
  alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setClickable(false);
} else {
  //set NegativeButton clickable
  alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setClickable(true);
}
```

Comment: @brian, probably need call alertDialog.show() first, I have updated my answer.